# Mule 4 stored procedure XMLType parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, database-connection, mule4, xmltype, mule-connector

We are using a stored procedure in Mule 4 to call the Oracle database, which contains a `XMLType` parameter as input for the stored procedure. I don't see any option to specify the type of the input parameter in the stored procedure. Can anyone please help me set the input parameter datatype value?

I tried sending payload input payload as `read(payload,"application/xml")` but I'm getting an error

```
Invalid column type
```

What is the correct way to send the input parameter of datatype `XMLType`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the XML to a string. The connector will convert it correctly. You are doing the opposite, reading it as an XML from a string. Instead use write(): `write(payload,"application/xml")`

Comment: I tried using write(payload,"application/xml") but getting error as "ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to store procedure". I was using correct number of parameters.

Comment: Please share the full operation in Mule and input data to reproduce the issue.